# How to find global npm's package.json?

Tags: npm

How can I find the `package.json` for npm that lists all globally installed packages? I know I can find the root with `npm root -g`, but I cannot find the `package.json` in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `npm list` inside the node_modules directory, it will list all the globally installed modules.